# Не могу поучить имя файла передаваемого клиентом серверу

Tags: java, android, сокет

Не могу поучить имя файла передаваемого клиентом. Вот код. Имя файла - первые 256 байт. Как получить `fname`???

Вот запуск сервера:

```
s = new Server();
mythread = new Thread(runnable);
mythread.start();
```

Код сервера:

```
public class Server implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket servsock;
    String fname;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int filesize=6022386;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;

        try {
        // create socket
         servsock = new ServerSocket(5554);
          while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

            // receive file
            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();

            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            fname = new String(mybytearray,0,256).replace(" ", "");


            do {
                bytesRead =
                        is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/" + f);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
                bos.flush();
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(end - start);
                bos.close();
                sock.close();

          }
        }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            }
        finally {
            try {
                servsock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      //  super.onDestroy();
        if (servsock != null) {
            try {
                servsock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема? Возникает ошибка, или что?

Comment: по-мелочи, раз вы все равно читаете весь файл, то определение имени лучше перенести ниже цикла, т.к. нет гарантии, что все 256 байт прочитаются с первого раза. Еще вы пишете на карту все, что прочитали, включая первые байты с именем.

Comment: Проблема в том, что файл не могу сохранить передаваемый файл под тем же  именем, т. е . передаётся от клиента с именем "order1.csv" и должен сохраниться на сервере под именем "order1.csv"

Comment: Да, спасибо, сам файл начинается с 256.

Comment: Предположу, что в конце строки, полученной из массива, добитого нулевыми байтами, не пробелы, а `(char)0`, попробуйте `replace("\0", "");`. Но вообще это криво, поведение конструктора при невозможности преобразовать байты в символы не определено. Лучше как-то передавать длину массива с кодированым именем файла, либо циклом определять первый нулевой символ.

Comment: `от клиента с именем "order1.csv" и должен сохраниться на сервере под именем "order1.csv"` - а сохраняется с каким именем?

Comment: Вообще не сохраняется. Если указать имя, то сохранится.

Comment: Если так  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/" + "order.csv");  , то всё сохраняется

Comment: а что тогда записывается в `fname `?

Comment: в fname записывается имя файла "order.csv", но файл не сохраняется под этим именем. Сохранится только тогда, когда прописать  fname="order.csv";

Comment: Имя файла получается после того, как должно выполнятся сохранение под этим именем...

Comment: Вот так работает fname = new String(mybytearray,0,256).replace("\0", "");

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @caxapyk81 По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Код сервера:
package com.example.saa.myapp;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket servsock;
    String fname;

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int filesize=6022386;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;

    try {
    // создаем сокет
     servsock = new ServerSocket(5554);
      while (true) {
        System.out.println("Ожидание подключений...");
        Socket sock = servsock.accept();
        System.out.println("Принятое подключение : " + sock);

        // получение файла
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();

        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;
        do {
            bytesRead =
                    is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
            if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
        } while(bytesRead > -1);

            fname = new String(mybytearray,0,256).replace("\0", "");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/" + fname);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 256,mybytearray.length-256);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end - start);
            bos.close();
            sock.close();
      }
    }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", " Ошибка", e);
        }
    finally {
        try {
            servsock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {     
    if (servsock != null) {
        try {
            servsock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Вот запуск сервера из activity:
  private Thread mythread;
  private Server s;

public void btn_runServer_onClick(View view) {
        s = new Server();
        mythread = new Thread(s);
        mythread.start();
        txt_status_server.setText(" Сервер запущен...");
    }
Вот остановка сервера:
    public void btn_stop_server_onClick(View view) {
        if (mythread != null) {
            Thread dummy = mythread;
            mythread = null;
            dummy.interrupt();
        }
        s.onDestroy();
        txt_status_server.setText(" Сервер остановлен");
    }